# Eigenvalues of graph laplacian question

Tags: spectral-theory, laplacian, spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

I need some guidance on solving the following question I am stuck on:

*Let L be a graph Laplacian matrix of a graph G = (V, E) with n vertices. Denote the eigenpairs of L by {λi,ψi} for every i=1..n, where the eigenvalues are sorted from the smallest to the largest. Let y1,y2,...,yk be orthonormal vectors that are all orthogonal to 1, where k<n. Show that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{k}y^\top_{i} L y_{i} \geq  \sum_{i=2}^{k+1}\lambda_{i}
\end{equation}
and find the condition when will be the inequality tight.*

**I tried** using the facts that L = D - A and
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i}d_{i}= \sum_{i}\lambda_{i}
\end{equation}
where $ \lambda $ are the eigenvalues, and $ d $ are the the diagonal elements of $ \mathbf{L} $.

I am currently stuck here and I don't know how to move on from here. I tried searching online and reading for some time now but didn't get any more ideas.

Thanks :)

Comment: try using Cauchy Eigenvalue Interlacing

Comment: @user8675309 I'm having a hard time seeing how this could theorem can help here... Could you give me another clue please?

Comment: let $Y$ be the $n\times k$ matrix with $\mathbf y_j$ as the jth column.  It satisfies $Y^TY =I_k$  and $\text{trace}\big(Y^TLY\big)= \sum_{i=1}^{k}y^\top_{i} L y_{i}$.  You can apply Cauchy Interlacing to bound the eigenvalues of $\big(Y^TLY\big)$.  Note: the standard indexing I've seen is for eigenvalues to be sorted $\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq \dots \geq \lambda_n$; if you aren't careful you'll get the indexing wrong when applying Interlacing